# magento 2.1.0 - currency conversion only on configurable products?

Tags: magento-2.1, multicurrency

I have i question about currency conversion.

Background:

We have a fresh install of Magento 2.1.0 CE and have stared to add content (products).

In the config we have 4 website, each with its own base currency. The base currency in the Default config is set to SEK.

When adding products we set the price in the base currency (SEK). We have also imported exchange rates between the currencies that we use.

Question:

When I added simple products, when displayed on the EUR website it shows the price set i SEK as in EUR. 119SEK displays as €119 (no conversion).

However when I added configurable products the price that display on the EUR website.

**Why does the conversion only work on the configurable products ? -- is there a setting for this etc.**

Also, should the conversion work on tier pricing (that is set i the base currency).

I have attached screenshots.

[image]